# Bootstrap 4 "hidden" class doesn't work consistently

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

I am having problems using the "hidden" class to hide content at a certain size. It works on some content, but not on others.

I use:

```
    <div class="hidden-sm">something to hide in small viewports </div>
```

I've tried it on navigation brand logo and it works, but it doesn't work on the navbar, some pictures etc...

Using the code below works (but hides it permanently)

```
<div hidden> something to hide in small viewports </div>
```

Using the code below doesn't work at all

```
<div hidden-sm> something to hide in small viewports </div>
```

Could someone explain the usage a little? Bootstrap docs don't provide too many details

Also, as you can clearly tell, I am not very good with CSS or JavaScript, so I would really rather just import bootstrap from the CDN without creating my own CSS files. (if possible)

Comment: Sorry about that, edited post

Comment: why don't you use the attribute class ?

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: your first example is using it, next are using made up attributes which have no meanings

Comment: Is there a way for me to know what the "hidden" class will apply to and what it won't? Such as, it applied only to divs, but not anchors or w/e; maybe you can mix "hidden" with other specific classes? What is the attribute class you are referring too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In html you have attributes like class, alt, src etc....

In your first case you're using the attribute class and providing a bootstrap class to it, which is why it works.

the second example you're using an html attribute called hidden and that is why it works.

the third code does not work because hidden-sm is not a valid attribute.  You need to say instead...

```
<div class="hidden-sm"> something to hide in small viewports </div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden

Comment: hey Chris, watched your django tutorial on youtube, awesome content! thank you for your contribution. :)    Regarding HTML attibutes; it makes sense now, however, it doesn't explain why sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Where and when can I use this bootstrap class?

Comment: Thank you!  You can use the class anywhere you would like by doing it the way your first example provides.   The rules dictating this class's styles are based on the width of the screen viewing the webpage.   So as you shrink your browser you'll notice the layout changes because the bootstrap CSS is using media queries to tell the browser to change styles when the screen is a certain width.    I would recommend you pull up your page in chrome.  Press F12 to open dev tools and look at the styles tab to see what styles are being applied.

Comment: Okay. I've played with it ALL night and I can't get images to hide at a certain size. I am using bootstrap 4 beta. Really don't know how to proceed, but I guess I will come back to it at a later date. Thanks for your help, guys and girls. :)